# Google chrome back ground not working in the stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet with a simple call to change background color
   `background-color: #fFfFfF;`
It works in IE but chrome it does not? any ideas please what I should do for various browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Changed too "background" -color not required